# unable to combine 2d arrays into another 2d array (python)

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have two lists,

```
    list_a
    list_b
```

whose shape are [10,50] and [40,50]
and I'm trying to combine them into one [50,50] array, starting with the following code (edited for readability)

```
    array_a=np.array(list_a)
    array_b=np.array(list_b)
    array_c=np.concatenate(array_a,array_b)
```

But it keeps giving me an error that says

"TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars"

What's the issue here, and how can I fix it? This error isn't very helpful...

Answer (score 2):

`np.concatenate` expects a tuple as argument, i.e. it should be

```
array_c=np.concatenate((array_a,array_b))
```

The first argument is a tuple of an arbitrary number of arrays, the second argument (in your case `array_b`) tells `concatenate` along which axis it should operate.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that `np.concatenate` expects an iterable sequence of array-like objects for the first argument.  Here it just takes `array_a` as the first argument.  It is taking `array_b` as the second argument, which specifies which array axis to concatenate along.  As this argument needs to be integer-like, it is attempting to convert `array_b` to an integer, but failing as it contains more than one item.  Hence this error message.

To solve it, you need to wrap your two arrays in an iterable such as a tuple, like this:

```
cc=np.concatenate((array_a,array_b))
```

This results in both arrays being passed as the first argument to the function.  (Edit: Wrapping in a list also works, i.e. `concatenate([array_a,array_b])`.  Haven't tried other forms).

In your example, this will work, as the second argument defaults to `0`, which means the arrays can have a different length in the first dimension only (the zeroth-indexed dimension).  For you, these lengths are `10` and `40`, and the other dimension is `50` for both.  If your array dimensions were reversed, so they were now `[50,10]` and `[50,40]`, you would need to set the axis to the second dimension (index `1`) like so:

```
cc=np.concatenate((array_a,array_b),1)
```